# Finding duplicates from large data set using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Lets assume that we have a big csv/excel file where there are big number of records against following fields.

```
1.Email 
2.First Name 
3.Last Name
4.Phone Number etc.
```

Among these records, we need to identify the duplicate records in terms of matching criteria of Email,First Name and Last Name.

For duplicate calculation,some custom rules are defined which gives a score against an individual record.

For example ,

```
1.If email is exact match then score is 100,else 0.

2.For First Name,Last Name etc. the edit distance is the score.
```

For example, lets assume that search parameter is like the following

```
Email:xyz@gmail.com,First Name: ABCD,Last Name:EFGH
```

The rows/records  are like

```
1.Email:xyz@gmail.com,First Name: ABC,Last Name:EFGH

2.Email:123xyz@gmail.com,First Name: ABC,Last Name:EFGH
```

For record1, score = 100(for email) + 75 (for first name) + 100 (for Last name)=**275**, i.e.**91.6%**

For record2, score = 0(for email) + 75 (for first name) + 100 (for Last name)=**175**, i.e.**58%**

Duplicate detection threshold is 75%,so record 1 is duplicate and record 2 is not.This is fairly simple to implement when we have input parameters and using them we want to determine the duplicates from a file.

**But how to apply this logic when we have all the records in a file and for all of them we need to find out which are the duplicate ones ?**

Here no input parameter is defined and we need to compare one record with all other records in order to find scoring relevance .

**How to achieve this in Apache Spark ?**

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into spark and apply group by on the email column.. after that check for bag and apply any distance algorithm on the first name and last name columns. This should be pretty straight forward in spark

```
val df = sc.textFile("hdfs path of data");

df.mapToPair("email", <whole_record>)
  .groupBy(//will be done based on key)
  .map(//will run on each bag )
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate bit further on this ,may be with some pseudo/sample code ? I was not able to understand it fully ,I am new to Spark .

Comment: hope this helps.. although I am not suppose to help you out with this.. as your question didn't show any efforts from your side in spark.